# Series expansion for $e^\frac{x^2}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

$$e^{-x^2}=1-x^2+\frac{x^4}{2!}-\frac{x^6}{3!}+\frac{x^8}{4!}+ \cdots$$
$$e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}=1+(\frac{x^2}{2})^2+(\frac{x^4}{2\cdot2!})^2+(\frac{x^6}{2\cdot3!})^2+(\frac{x^8}{2\cdot4!})^2+\cdots$$
$=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}=1+\dfrac{x^4}{8}+\dfrac{x^{8}}{4\cdot2!}-\dfrac{x^{12}}{8\cdot3!}+\dfrac{x^{16}}{16\cdot4!}+\cdots$

Wolfram's answer is $e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}=1+\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^4}{4\cdot2!}+\dfrac{x^6}{8\cdot3!}+\dfrac{x^8}{16\cdot4!}+\cdots$

So what is wrong with my computation? Is Wolfram correct, I suspect that it cannot be wrong.

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Comment: I don't see you you got your formula for $e^{x^2/2}$.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown: I just replace $x^2$ with $\frac{x^2}{2}$

Comment: As I understand, you're using series for $e^{x^2}$ to write $e^{x^2/2}$. This means, you should write $e^{x^2/2} = e^{(x/\sqrt{2})^2}$, not $e^{(x^2/2)^2}$.

Comment: You wrote down a formula that is manifestly incorrect. I cannot fathom why you did that.

Comment: Can you help me to correct it?

Comment: If you replace $x^2$ by $x^2/2$ in the series for $\exp(x^2)$ you do get Wolfie's formula.

Comment: So I don't need to double the power again? Is this how substitution done?

Comment: Try using $x=(y^2/2)$ - ie different names for the variables - that will help you to avoid getting confused. You need to substitute into the formula for $e^{x}$. You have also managed to square the factorials in one part of your workings, but have not carried that through (it was wrong in the first place).

Answer (score 3):

$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+...$

So you just plug in $x^2/2$ for $x$ and this gives you what Wolfram gave you.

Comment: I didn't choose $e^x$ because I have already expanded $e^{-x^2}$ in my notebook.